# Call another shell script with argument which contains whitespce

Tags: linux, shell, arguments

Script A:

```
#!/bin/bash
. foo.sh
ARGS="a \"b c\" d"
./foo.sh $ARGS
```

Script foo:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
```

After executing script A, I got the following result:

a

"b

c"

d

My expected result is:

a

b c

d

Could somebody tell me the reason, and how to change to get the expected result, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store multiple arguments with white-spaces better to use shell arrays:

```
ARGS=(a "b c" d)
```

and call the script as

```
./foo.sh "${ARGS[@]}"
```

This will print:

```
a
b c
d
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the result is not corret, acutally, it's same as the previous one.

Comment: Can you make sure you're running `bash` before attempting this.

Comment: bash A.sh
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d

Comment: Thanks, I miss the quote, it works now, thans very much.